# Which architecture is this CNN model belongs to?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I need some help to find which architecture does this CNN Model belongs to, like leNet, GoogleNet, etc..

```
input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 10

model = models.Sequential([
resize_and_rescale,
layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
])

model.build(input_shape=input_shape)
```

[Model Summary image link is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dG9q.png)

Comment: Why do you think it belongs to any specific architecture?

Comment: some architecture have the same convolution, relu layers, etc So I confused which architecture does it belong to

Comment: This model seems pretty basic to be of any specific architectures, seems like a regular convolutional neural network to me.

Comment: CNN architecture consists of many Convolutional and other layers to be used to classify several object categories by using its pretrained weights as a transfer learning model and to save the developer time of defining large model to get optimized performance. There are several [CNN architectures](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications) available to use based on its features. Please check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/top-10-cnn-architectures-every-machine-learning-engineer-should-know-68e2b0e07201) link for your reference to know more about CNN architectures.